# How do I sign a file with my smartcard on Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: signature, smartcard

I own a latitude E7240 with a smartcard reader (broadcom 5880), running Ubuntu 20.10, and a smartcad with a qualified certificate which I want to usu to digitally sign files.

Cardpeek correctly sees the reader and the smartcard.

While previously I had no problems under Windows, I have found no usable app to sign files in Ubuntu.

Any suggestion?

Comment: There was a recent blog last few days about this in stack exchange epost. Look for one there. I looked it up for you https://www.facebook.com/ubuntulinux/posts/10158703843868592:0

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue using an app distributed by poste.it
other options such as dike, the estonian app, etc. all had issues with groovy gorilla